# Migrating site to a new server, do I need a new connection ticket and certificates for Intuit QBMS?

Tags: migration, intuit-partner-platform

I have a site that uses QBMS to process credit card transactions. I'm moving the site from one hosting company to another, but keeping the same domain name.

Do I need to get or update a new connection ticket and new certificates, or will they work once the domain name resolves to the new server? If so, how would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you also migrate any related SSL certificates, then you can use the same connection ticket.

You should also update your reverse DNS while you're at it (ask your hosting provider).